# VB silverlight for windows phone remote databases

Tags: mysql, vb.net, wcf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i am writing some applications for windows phone on VB

i want to connect on a remote database in order to exchange data
but i do not want to use WCF  (Like this : [WCF](http://studentguru.gr/b/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx)) `http://studentguru.gr/b/dt008/archive/2010/12/02/querying-a-database-on-windows-phone-7-using-wcf.aspx`
 but i want to use a simple MySql
because i can easilly find some free hosts !
for WCF it is impossible to find and test that easy :)

so.... do you have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect directly to a MySQL database on a remote server. If you don't use WCF as an intermediary you'll have to use something equivalent such as ODATA or some other web/REST service.